# Смысл префикса -z перед строковой переменной в bash

Tags: linux, bash

По долгу службы столкнулся с необходимость адаптировать bash-скрипт и т.к. раньше с ними не работал, возникли вопросы, не все из которых получилось сходу загуглить.
Есть условный оператор

```
if [ -z "$SOMEVAR" ] || [ -z "$OTHERVAR" ]; then
    <operations>
fi
```

В $SOMEVAR содержится строковая переменная. Очевидно, отдельные условия заключаются в скобки [] в bash. При этом, соединение в виде ||, судя по телу условного оператора можно интерпретировать как "И". Но что значит -z в этой конструкции?

Здесь же задам похожий вопрос. Есть условный оператор:

```
if [ -z "$CFGFILENAME" ] || [ ! -f $CFGFILENAME ]; then
    echo "Configuration file is not found"
    exit 2
fi
```

Очевидно, он работает похожим образом, но помимо -z перед переменной, хранящей адрес до файла есть еще и префикс "! -f". Где "!", вероятно, можно интерпретировать как "НЕ", но что такое тогда -f? Тем более, что в этот раз переменная не заключена в кавычки. Очевидно, конструкция как-то проверяет наличие файла, но механизм не совсем понятен.

Comment: Все это относится к программе [test](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/testh.html). `-z STRING      True if string is empty.`

Comment: -z проверяет наличие переменной, -f проверяет наличие файла, ! -f логическое условие и сработает если файла нет.

Comment: То есть подразумевается использование test при любом упоминании используемых в ней флагов в случайном месте? или это просто сокращение и `if [ test -z "$SOMEVAR" ]` тоже корректно?

Comment: Квадратные кавычки - это и есть сокращенная запись `test`. Правильно будет так: `if test -z "$SOMEVAR" ;`

Comment: @NewView я бы сказал, что `-z` проверяет значение переменной на "не пустое". Переменная может существовать но быть "пустой", вот так `a=""`, т.е. переменная в наличии есть, но `-z` в этом случае вернет True.

Comment: @ВиталийЯндулов Загляните в каталог /usr/bin вы там найдете исполнимый файл, называющийся `[`, который является обычно жесткой ссылкой на test. bash же очень простой, он сам понимает только if а все что после просто пытается выполнить и посмотреть код завершения

Comment: @Mike как раз bash очень развесистый и test в нём это встроенная команда. См man bash раздел Shell builtin commands

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> if [ -z "$SOMEVAR" ] || [ -z "$OTHERVAR" ]; then
> ```

если данная команда интерпретируется программой *bash*, то используется встроенная реализация программы `[` (она же является синоноимом другой встроенной реализации программы `test`). эта реализация полностью соответствует тому, что изложено в стандарте [*posix*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) относительно этих программ (`[` и `test`).

синтаксис вызова программ `[` и `test` (в операционной системе *gnu* они обычно располагаются в каталоге `/usr/bin`), как он [описан](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) в стандарте:

```
[ выражение ]
test выражение
```

здесь закрывающая скобка `]` является обязательным (последним) аргументом программы `[`.

полный синтаксис выражения, как можно видеть по приведённой выше ссылке, весьма «развесист». остановлюсь на трёх упомянутых в вопросе моментах:

1. проверка строки на длину:

   ```
   -z "строка"
   ```

   программа вернёт *true* только если строка имеет нулевую длину, иначе *false*
2. проверка на существование файла:

   ```
   -f "путь-к-файлу"
   ```

   программа вернёт *true* только если "путь-к-файлу" ссылается на «обычный» файл, иначе *false*
3. инверсия:

   ```
   ! выражение
   ```

   программа вернёт *true* если выражение возвращает *false*

---

по поводу `||`. это довольно распространённая в языках программирования конструкция, используемая в логических выражениях как оператор *или* (*or*).

не имеет отношения ни к программе `[` (`test`), ни к её встроенной в программу *bash* реализации. это уже оператор самой оболочки (в данном случае — программы *bash*).